# Service call failed while launching the gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends

I tried launching gazebo with the following commands:

1. roscore
2. $ roslaunch youbot_description youbot_arm_description.launch  
    3. $ roslaunch youbot_description youbot_arm_publisher.launch

...... so first 2 are working fine and when I try to do 3rd one to launch gazebo it says gazebo successfully initialized and model was shown for 2 secs and after that it says process has died as described below..... so please if anyone can help it would be of great help ..... please try to help us.

```
Gazebo successfully initialized
/home/youbot/ros_stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Main simulation loop failed
/home/youbot/ros_stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
spawning success None
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 2498, exit code -11].
log files: /home/youbot/.ros/log/e142418c-136d-11e1-ad57-002682c60600/gazebo-2*.log
[youbot_gazebo_model-3] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/youbot/.ros/log/e142418c-136d-11e1-ad57-002682c60600/youbot_gazebo_model-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12032/service-call-failed-while-launching-the-gazebo/) by [Ganta Kranthi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1413/ganta-kranthi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-02-29**:
Please update your original question and mark the answer to your question when available instead of posting new questions as "answers".  This is not an e-mail thread, it's a Q&A/Stackoverflow forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your log says that Gazebo couldn't find the file `libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so`. It's in the package pr2_gazebo_plugins (in the stack pr2_simulator), so make sure that pr2_simulator is installed and run a `rosmake pr2_gazebo_plugins`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1